# Laravel 6 and Bootstrap

Tags: laravel, sass, version

I am new to Laravel.

When I install Laravel 6 a lot of the things that install by default in Laravel 5.8 are not evident i.e. bootstrap, vue, jquery.

I see this is package.json file.

I did not find anything that explains this and wondering if anyone has some guidance that might enlighten me.

Example:

I was trying to use bootstrap as shown in the video I was watching and found missing resources/sass files ap.scss and .variables.scss. ap.scss was empty and .variables.scss was absent. I did find them buried elsewhere in the installation; however, bootstrap did not work and any attempts I made to install bootstrap and other missing pieces wound up breaking the framework (probably something I did.)

In the meantime I am staying with a Version 5 distribution of Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel decoupled what front end tech you use by default in 6.0

You can review the documentation here.

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/frontend